# Как правильно писать словосочетание?

Tags: лексика

Как правильно писать: *хостельный номер* или *номер хостел?*

Answer (score 1):

В орфографическом словаре: [хо́стел](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB), -а *(вид отеля)*.

В большом толковом словаре:
ХОСТЕЛ *[тэ]*, -а; ***м.*** [от англ. hostel — общежитие]
Общежитие, дешёвая гостиница, предоставляющая постояльцам спальное место в комнате без дополнительных удобств.

Прилагательное [хостельный](https://classes.ru/all-polish/dictionary-polish-russian-uni-term-18172.htm) существует (хостельный бизнез, хостельный рынок), поэтому можно сказать и *хостельный номер*, и *номер* (чего?) *хостел**а***, и *номер* (в чём?) *в хостеле*.